# Java: time delay on a specific position - works in the wrong place

Tags: java, user-interface, time, delay, thread-sleep

I don't know if the title actually makes my problem clear. I'm making a card game application. When the user and the computer both have played their cards off they should remain on the screen there for a certain until the computer plays the next card off. 
I tried to solve this problem using thread.sleep() in try catch. And it's basically doing what it's supposed to do but it's not what I want it to do. The delay isn't between the computer playing one card and then the second one off. It is between the user pushing the button (for a card) and the appearance of this card on screen.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jLabel1.setIcon(//new Icon of the card);
    jPanel1.remove(jButton1);
    jLabel2.setIcon(//new Icon of the card);
    if(//proving whether the computer played the highest amount off)
    {
        disableButtons();

            sleep();//waiting for a certain time...
            playCard();//...until playing the next card off
    }
}                                        




       public void sleep()
{   

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: please post your code for help

Comment: I don't think we can help you without a little bit of code. Also, it#d help to know what kind of user-interface you're using? Console? Swing?

Comment: Without any actual code your problem is difficult to solve. Maybe you could add some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. If you sleep in the UI thread, the UI will not reflect all your drawing commands until you enter the main loop again. Look into [swing timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).